# Reload scene in unity activates UI that shouldn't be activated

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rckvN.png*)

so by default GameOverMenu is disabled and when my player dies it gets activated, then when i revive player and scene reloads it becomes active from the start, how can i prevent this? how do i make it so that GaveOverMenu is disabled always until the player dies.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can create script and attach it to your GameOverMenu which has declared `void Awake()` method. In this method you can disable game object by calling `gameObject.SetActive(false)` - it's gonna be called when scene starts/reloads.